# What is the purpose of people and animals having green plants for food in Gen 1?

Tags: genesis, revelation, temple

Let's assume for a moment (a controversial point) that Genesis was written by Moses whilst in the wilderness as a song of comfort for his people. (Who were probably not eating food that they would have preferred).

We read in Genesis 1:

> <sup>29</sup> Then God said, “I give you every seed-bearing plant on the face of the whole earth and every tree that has fruit with seed in it. They will be yours for food. <sup>30</sup> And to all the beasts of the earth and all the birds in the sky and all the creatures that move along the ground—everything that has the breath of life in it—I give every green plant for food.” And it was so.

Now we assume that pre-fall we still had free will, but that man was content with the Boundaries of God.

We also know that Genesis 1 was a 'type of temple' in which man dwelt in the presence of God. We know that in Revelation, post-sin man will also dwell in the presence of God. In Revelation the place with God is a 'garden temple'. So perhaps the eating 'salad' in Genesis 1 is a reference to eating with God in the garden temple as it will be in Heaven.

My assumption is that we are reading the Bible in light of Systematic Theology - ie we interpret the Bible using the Bible.

My question is: **What is the purpose of people and animals having green plants for food in Gen 1?**

Comment: It means God provides even for the animals. Allegorising about free will is surely completely out of context.

Comment: Question closed at the request of the OP.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The purpose is to provide nourishment for man and beast without the need to shed blood.

God's creation is good.

> And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good.
> Gen 1:35 ESV

See also Gen 1:4, 10, 12, 18, 21, 25.

The food chain we observe now requires the death of animals so that they become food in the chain.  Death is unnatural and a result of the fall.

> And the LORD God made for Adam and for his wife garments of skins and
> clothed them. Gen 3:21
>
> For the wages of sin is death... Rom 6:23

God gave the green plant for the animals as food.  Giving the green plant as food is good because it does not require death to any of God's creation.

Comment: Answers on this site are required to [show their work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/536/2757). Can you please [edit] this to add some evidence or logical basis for this position?